# LINQ to JSON: how to get the right format?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, json, linq-to-entities

im trying to convert my result from a linq query to json
using [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/LINQtoJSON.html)

here is what i did:

```
JObject o = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    UserID = from u in model.USER
             select new
             {
                 UserID = u.UserID
             }
});
```

here is what i get:

```
JSON
  id=1
  result={"UserID":[{"UserID":121},"UserID":121},{"UserID":122},{"UserID":123},{"UserID":124}]}
```

here is what i need:

```
JSON
  id=1
  result={[{UserID:'121'},{UserID:'121'},{UserID:'122'},{UserID:'123'},{UserID:'124'}]}
```

how do i get this done? thank you

Comment: Aren't they practically equivalent? Do you really need unquoted keys? You can probably get string values with `u.UserID.ToString()` if you really need them.

Comment: its not the quotes the problem (at least i dont think so) , but the 'userId' in the begining

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
 JArray a = JArray.FromObject(
                from u in model.USER
                select new
                {
                    UserID = u.UserID
                }
    );
```

Comment: it doesnt accept it,i already tried , u cant put the query directly i guess `Compiler Error Message: CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.`

Comment: thx,i got `Object serialized to Array.  JObject instance expected`

Comment: @astrocybernaute this one: `{[{UserID:'121'},...]}` is actually an array, not an object.

Comment: ok..but im not sure what do u mean? use JArray instead of JObject ??!

Comment: @astrocybernaute yes, try JArray